# The `inflate` of layoutInflater is showing as unresolved when trying to bind - Kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, binding

I'm trying to use binding to get an id, but when I setup my binding line `binding = ActvityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` the `inflate` is red and saying that it is an unresolved reference.  It gives different options for importing, but none of those options resolve the issue.  They just import something and `inflate` is still red

```html
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import com.example.postrequestspike.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

const val BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActvityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        getMyData()
    }
```

Here are some screenshots:
`inflate` shows unresolved reference
[image: inflate shows unresolved reference]

options are shown after clicking import
[image: options are shown after clicking import]

options import but do not resolve the reference
[image: options import but do not resolve the reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in this case I made a spelling error. (See `binding = ActvityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`)